# Xamarin EF Core database migration deletes old data

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a Xamarin mobile app that I've added some new features to, for which I also added new database tables. I also created a new migration for these. But when I run this migration it actually clears all the old data from the db, instead of just adding the tables etc.

To create the migration I followed the instructions by MarkSmith.8123 [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101805/xamarin-android-entity-framework-core-2-and-migrations). And I have actually made a migration once before, using the same instructions.

To try it, I first install the app from Google Play. I log in, make some local changes, and then shutdown the app. Then I install the new version (with the migration) by debugging in Visual Studio. When I start the app again all the old data is gone, log in info and local changes. I've also tried making the first install from an earlier commit (without new stuff) with Visual Studio, without any noticeable difference.

I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 2.0.1.

```
public class MyDbContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
    ...

    public MyDbContext(string databasePath)
    {
        DatabasePath = databasePath;
        AddInitialMigrationForPreMigrationInstalls();
        Database.Migrate();
    }

    private void AddInitialMigrationForPreMigrationInstalls()
    {
        if (Database.Exists()) // This is just an extension doing: dbFacade.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().Exists()
        {
            Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ""__EFMigrationsHistory"" (
                    ""MigrationId"" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ""PK___EFMigrationsHistory"" PRIMARY KEY,
                    ""ProductVersion"" TEXT NOT NULL
                );

                INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ""__EFMigrationsHistory"" (""MigrationId"", ""ProductVersion"")
                VALUES ('20180829103834_InitialCreate', '2.0.1-rtm-125');        
            ");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={DatabasePath}");
    }

    ...
}
```

I expect all the data in db to be untouched, while the new tables should have been added.

I don't really know how to examine this further. How can I see what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android apps are sandboxed. Your side-loaded app cannot access the database file of an app downloaded from the Google Play store.

When you install from a prior commit, the update has access to the prior version's data.

Use Google's beta testing features described here:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/test-tracks

Comment: That makes sense. Something else came up right now, but I will try out the beta testing features asap, and then return here and mark as answer if it solved my problem.